# iis7.5 Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

When I accessed my website(coded with `asp.net`) on `iis7.5`, it occurred the problem below. I have no idea but just restarting it. What should I do about the problem? Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As your Error Message reads set debug=true. Check your `web.config` `connectionStrings` section and make sure you can connect to the resources listed there.

Comment: As it is an Ole DB related error, you will have to dig the legacy technology documentation to see how to dig the exact logging. If possible, use modern things, such as `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: I solved it. The reason is that sql server automaticly closed. Thank you for your answers.